# What is the difference between the -monochrome and the -colorspace GRAY options?

Tags: imagemagick

I want to convert a PDF of text to black and white, and was wondering if there was any difference between

```
convert -monochrome in.pdf out.pdf
```

and

```
convert -colorspace GRAY in.pdf out.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

The output with `-monochrome` is black and white without any colors inbetween while `-colorspace` converts the input into the given destination colorspace.

[gm convert options](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html#conv-opti):

> `-monochrome`
>   transform the image to black and white

[gm convert colorspace](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-colorspace):

> `-colorspace <value>`
>     the type of colorspace
>    ...
>   Two gray colorspaces are supported. The **Rec601Luma** space is based on the recommendations for legacy NTSC television (ITU-R BT.601-5). 
>   The **Rec709Luma** space is based on the recommendations for HDTV (Rec. ITU-R BT.709-5) and is suitable for use with computer graphics, 
>   and for contemporary CRT displays. The **GRAY** colorspace currently selects the **Rec601Luma** colorspace by default for backwards compatibly reasons. This default may be re-considered in the future.
>   ...

Here is an example of an image conversion, the output for PDFs would be similar.

Input image:
[image: input image]

Output `-monochrome`:
[image: -monochrome]

Output `-colorspace GRAY` (Rec601Luma)
[image: -colorspace GRAY]